# Error while Launching activity - Android Studio 2.1

Tags: java, android

I'm completely new to android studio, and after hours of trying to figure out how to run an emulator on an AMD CPU, when I finally run (a completely base project btw) it says:

> Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "payne.jackson.test/payne.jackson.test.Main" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Error while Launching activity

I don't know what is wrong. 
I tried deleting all of my AVD files and that didn't work.

EDIT: I also get these errors when launching my emulator:

emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
Creating filesystem with parameters:

I found something saying to switch to a nexus 4, but that didn't work.
Still don't know what is wrong.

For those of you who wanted logcat it was too long but I noticed a lot of lines saying something along the lines of this:

05-08 10:01:40.185 78-78/? W/Resources: Preloaded drawable resource #0x10803dd (android:drawable/ic_menu_paste_holo_dark) that varies with configuration!!

Could this be the problem?

Comment: post your activity class and logcat completetly

Comment: Also you might post the manifest file alongside what @zahanSafallwa said.